# How to know list of sites visited on my computer using resolvers

Tags: dns

I don't want to look at Browser's history or other monitoring tools to find out sites visited on my computer.

I know that for every domain, browser sends a domain name resolution request to DNS server through name resolvers on my Windows PC.

Is it possible to grab that list sent to name resolver on Windows sent by client programs like Telnet, Browsers etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://www.opendns.com/ to accomplish this. You will have to manually specify your DNS settings on your PC OR router.

I would prefer making this setting change on your router so that any user would not see the manually set DNS settings.

You can then use the reporting tools on OpenDns to see the domains that were visited.

Comment: But where will I see the list of websites visited?

Comment: You'll see them on the control panel on opendns.

Comment: After making setting change in the route will I need to change any settings in the Windows too?

Comment: Once you make the DNS change on the router, your computers will pull down that info if they are set to obtain DNS settings automatically. They might need a reboot to do this.